get hospital count in a city using google maps API
I am trying to use google maps api to get a list of all hospitals in a city. But how can I create a "radius" or "bounding box" or a city, for example Munich, Germany? When I search, I get a single coordinate set. But how can I obtain all hospitals in a particular city/area using the api?
Is it even possible to get coordinates of an entire city's coverage? I tried this but with this random radius, I get really wrong results:
import requests

def count_hospitals(api_key):
    # Define the endpoint for Places API Nearby Search
    endpoint = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json"

    # Define the latitude and longitude coordinates for Munich
    munich_coordinates = "48.1351,11.5820"  # Munich's coordinates

    # Define parameters for the API request
    params = {
        "location": munich_coordinates,
        "radius": 50000,  # Search radius in meters, adjust as needed
        "type": "hospital",  # Search for hospitals
        "key": api_key  # Your API key
    }

    # Send the HTTP request to the API
    response = requests.get(endpoint, params=params)
    data = response.json()

    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 200 and 'results' in data:
        hospitals_count = len(data['results'])
        print("Number of hospitals in Munich:", hospitals_count)
    else:
        print("Error occurred while fetching data:", data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
    count_hospitals(api_key)


Note that I might not be "nearby" even if I am using the nearby endpoint.

Check out How to get all places
